# masstransit.messageexception: anonymous types are not valid message types

Tags: c#, masstransit

I got
`"masstransit.messageexception: anonymous types are not valid message types"` with below

```cs
_bus.Publish(Ids.Select(id=>new SomeEvent()));
```

I googled and didn't find anything directly solving my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I realized it should be the SomeEvent object instead of IEnumerable to be published.

As IEnumerable is not a namespaced object, it will cause this exception.