# Could not send list of custom objects via Publish method of IPublishEndpoint in MassTransit (Messages types must not be System type)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

Note this is not a duplicate question of [MassTransit messages types must not be System types exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738811/masstransit-messages-types-must-not-be-system-types-exception).

I am using `RabbitMQ` version 8.0.2 in `Asp.NET Core Web API (.Net 6)`. I can publish **a custom object** successfully by using `Publish` method of `IPublishEndpoint`, however, whenever I try to send publish **List of the object** I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Messages types must not be System type
```

Here is the full sample:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;
        public WeatherForecastController(IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
        {
            _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                    { "key1", "value1" },
                                    { "key2", "value2" }
                                }
            }).ToList();

            //Error!
            await _publishEndpoint.Publish<IList<WeatherForecast>>(data);

            //Working 
           //await _publishEndpoint.Publish<WeatherForecast>(data.FirstOrDefault());
            
            return data;
        }
    }
```

And in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(options => {
    options.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost:5672"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
    });
});
```

Why I can't use `IList` with `Publish` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `IList<T>` with `Publish` because it isn't supported. There are some `PublishBatch` extension methods that enumerate the list and call `Publish` for each element.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it's not supported. Because it supports `List` as a property of class!

Comment: Is there a documentation that refers to this limitation?

Comment: If you look in the log, the exception generated indicates that system types cannot be used as message types.

Comment: Basically the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697438/1882).

Comment: Now based on you suggestion I am using `PublishBatch` but My data goes to skipped queue and I can't consume it. why?

Comment: That's another question, and you don't ask questions in answers on SO. Maybe search for skipped, you might [find an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65887692/masstransit-rabbitmq-why-are-all-my-messages-skipped).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an IList, which is not supported as Chris Patterson described, I put my List data in an object and returned this. So in this case it would be an object with your list of objects.